# npm copyfiles maintain full path

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, build-script

I am trying to copy some patched files from my config to the node modules. I want to maintain the directory path with the file.

For example:

I am running:

```
copyfiles -u 1 ./config/patches/ ./node_modules/
```

I expect the files in:

```
./config/patches/core/testing1/fix1.js
./config/patches/core/testing2/fix2.js
```

to look like this:

```
./node_modules/core/testing1/fix1.js
./node_modules/core/testing2/fix2.js
```

However, nothing is copied in

Answer (score 3):

Change your `copyfiles` command to either of the following depending on how/where it is being invoked:

1. **Running the command directly via your CLI:**

   If the `copyfiles` package has been installed globally, then run the following command via your CLI:

   ```
   copyfiles -u 2 "./config/patches/core/**" "./node_modules/"
   ```
2. **Running the command via an npm-script**

   If the `copyfiles` package has been installed locally, then configure the `scripts` section of your `package.json` as follows:

   ```json
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "quux": "copyfiles -u 2 \"./config/patches/core/**\" \"./node_modules/\""
   },
   ...
   ```

**Notes:**

- The `-u` option has been set to `2` levels.
- The input path goes down the tree one more level to the `core` directory.
- Double globstars (`**`) have also been appended to the input path.
- Both the input and output paths have been escaped in double quotes to avoid expansion. When the command is used in JSON (i.e. an npm-script as per the second example) the double quotes will need to be escaped (i.e. `\"...\"`).